# the car runs strong no miss or bad mounts. it vibrates/ not missing when in neutral but goes smooth with any load even turning on the air

Tags: chevrolet

First I would like to say I am a very qualified mechanic who has been a trouble shooter for a lot of years. this engine runs with no miss and has no miss issues. after the break in period I notice a vibration, not a miss when idling in neutral. This goes away when put into gear or any load is on the engine.  I have encountered this only one time on an Onan diesel.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Agreeing with HandyHowie I really don't know what your question is here or what exactly the problem is you are trying to solve. Could you please edit your question and include your the information you are in need of so we can possibly help you out? Would be greatly appreciated!